# cannot convert emojis into text sentiment from social media comments

Tags: python, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I have collected data from facebook and twitter comments on a product advertisement and trying to do sentiment analysis on these comments. Part of the text cleanup involves converting emojis into text sentiment in order to maximise capturing all sentiment in comments. I have tried emoji.demojize(text) per row and various other approaches from stackoverflow but none of them convert the emojis in the comments to actual sentiment in words.The code below does not work. Not sure what my mistake is. Here is the code:

```
enter import io
import json

def handleEmojis(text, keep_emoticons = False):
global emoji_sentiment_matching
if not 'emoji_sentiment_matching' in globals():
    with io.open('emoji.json', 'r', encoding = "UTF-8") as outfile:
        emoji_sentiment_matching = json.load(outfile)
HASHTAG_PATTERN = re.compile(r'#\w*')
EMOJIS_PATTERN_PLAIN_TEXT = re.compile(r"(?:X|:|;|=)(?:-)?(?:\)|\(|O|D|P|S){1,}", re.IGNORECASE)
EMOJIS_PATTERN_SYMBOLS = re.compile(u'[\U00002600-\U000027BF]|[\U0001f300-\U0001f64F]|[\U0001f680-\U0001f6FF]')

if keep_emoticons:
    # Replace emoji with sentiment
    for emoji in emoji_sentiment_matching:
        if emoji["emoji"] in text:

            ## Adding space if text follows right away / is right before the emoticon
            idx = text.find(emoji["emoji"])
            (space1,space2) = ("","")
            if (idx-1) >= 0 and text[idx-1] != " ":
                space1 = " "
            if (idx+1) <= len(text) and text[idx+1] != " ":
                space2 = " "

            ## replace emoticon with its sentiment
            text = text.replace(emoji["emoji"], "{}emoji%%{}{}".format(space1, emoji["subgroup"], space2))}
            

## TO IMPLEMENT: Sentiment of other emoticons like :), :-), :-/


else:
    for r in re.findall(EMOJIS_PATTERN_SYMBOLS,text):
        text = text.replace(r, "")
    for r in re.findall(EMOJIS_PATTERN_PLAIN_TEXT,text):
        text = text.replace(r, "")
return text.strip()


import io
import json

FB_df['demojified']=FB_df['Text'] 
for i in range(len(FB_df)):
  text = FB_df.loc[i,"demojified"]
  handleEmojis(text, keep_emoticons = False)

print(FB_df)
```

and this is the resultant output (refer to 'demojified' column):
[dataframe outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZkrN.png)

I have also tried the following code as well:

```
import re
from emot.emo_unicode import UNICODE_EMO, EMOTICONS
from emoji import demojize
def convert_emojis(text):
for emot in UNICODE_EMO:
    text = re.sub(r'('+emot+')', "_".join(UNICODE_EMO[emot].replace(",","").replace(":","").split()), text)
return text
```

Converting emoticons to words

```
def convert_emoticons(text):
for emot in EMOTICONS:
    text = re.sub(u'('+emot+')', "_".join(EMOTICONS[emot].replace(",","").split()), text)
    return text

FB_df['demojified']=FB_df['Text'] 

for row in FB_df['demojified']:
for text in row:
    text=text
    convert_emojis(text)

FB_df.loc[:,'demojified']
```

And still no joy. I have been at this for a week. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated please

I have also tried:

```
I have also tried: 
import re
from emot.emo_unicode import UNICODE_EMO, EMOTICONS
from emoji import demojize
def convert_emojis(text):
for emot in UNICODE_EMO:
    text = re.sub(r'('+emot+')',
"_".join(UNICODE_EMO[emot].replace(",","").replace(":","").split()), text)
return text
```

Converting emoticons to words

```
def convert_emoticons(text):
for emot in EMOTICONS:
    text = re.sub(u'('+emot+')', 
"_".join(EMOTICONS[emot].replace(",","").split()), text)
    return text
FB_df['demojified']=FB_df['Text'] 
for row in FB_df['demojified']:
 for text in row:
    text=str(text)
    text = emoji.demojize(text)
```

And still no joy :-(

Answer (score 1):

problem identified. I had forgotten to update the demojified column with the output in the for-loop

```
FB_df['Demojified']=FB_df['Comments'] 
for i in range(len(FB_df.Demojified)):
  text = FB_df.loc[i,"Demojified"]
  text=emoji.demojize(text)
  text = text.replace(":"," ")
  text = ' '.join(text.split())
  FB_df.loc[i,"Demojified"] = text

FB_df=FB_df[['Title','Comments','Demojified']]
```